# Delphi FMX form from a library (dll) into a panel in the main application

Tags: forms, delphi, dll, panel, firemonkey

I've tried to follow the example of:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FMXEmbeddedForm_(Delphi)

but the form elements just don't appear. I'm using Delphi 10.3 and compiling for Windows.
If both the form and the panel are in the library project or in the program project, then it works well.

It's needed to work both in Windows and MacOS.

Comment: That example does not mention a DLL. Implementing UI using DLLs is known to be very troublesome. This is what packages are for.

Comment: As David says, it's a terrible idea to implement a form inside of a DLL, especially if it's in FMX. For starters, the DLL would have its own `Application` instance, which is useless in the context of the DLL, and therefore no Windows message pump. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @Jerry That's not the reason why using DLLs in this way is problematic. There's a message pump. The message pump isn't associated with a module, but with a thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's kinda what I meant, I just didn't explain it right. It's still true that the `Application` instance is entirely unrelated, and thus useless, and the message pump does need to be considered. Either way, that's just one example of why one should never think about putting a form inside of a DLL. There are endless other challenges. Yes, packages would work, but even then, it's probably the wrong solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Since I'm translating a large VCL software into FireMonkey, I wonder if the best solution would be merging the DLL with the program (or at least the embedded forms). I think the packages solution would require more work because the forms are very interconnected.

Comment: Regarding the windows message pump, are sendmessage and postmessage not enabled is what you are saying? Because they seem to work in vcl as I tried them.

Comment: @Jerry What is the message pump for... try sending SendMessage and PostMessage and it still works, or are you talking about another pump. There is no concept of a pump in MSDN or in the delphi source code to look at. Give us a unit that the pump exists in? and what's the TObject called?

Answer (score 0):

To have an FMX form in a DLL, you must create a DLL and add the form you need.
In the DLL, you have to expose an API which present your DLL (One or more) as a flat API, that is ordinary functions and procedures (not methods) to create/destroy the form, show/hide it and anything else you may need.

For event in the form, your DLL must implement a callback mechanism. When an event is triggered (for example a button click), you must call the appropriate callback.

The main application will load the DLL as usual, calling Windows LoadLibray function. Then is will call the API you designed to create the form, make it visible, set his bounds and setup any required callback.

Attaching the form in DLL somewhere in an FMX form in the calling application is somewhat challenging. FMX components, except a TForm doesn't have the window handle which is required to have the form in the DLL seen inside the application form.

If you are happy with attaching the DLL's form inside an application form, then it is easy because any FMX form has a method FormToHWND() to get the window handle for the form. It can be passed to the DLL. The DLL has to use that handle to set the parent window of the form in the DLL.

I have created a simple application and corresponding DLL.
The DLL has a single form with a TLabel, a TEdit and a TButton.
The application has a single form with two TButtons (to create/show and hide the form in the DLL), and a TMemo to display data from the DLL.

In the DLL, the button is used to send the data to the main application by using a callback.

Here is the code:

```
{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Author:       Francois.PIETTE@overbyte.be
Creation:     Jan 14, 2020
Description:  Demo app for FMX form in a DLL
Disclaimer:   This is free software. Use it at your own risks.
Version:      1.00
History:


 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
unit FomInDllAppMain;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
    System.Variants, System.IOUtils,  WinApi.Windows,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
    FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Platform.Win,
    FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
    TInDllCreateForm                = function  (ParentHWnd : HWnd): HWnd;
                                                stdcall;
    TInDllProc                      = procedure;  stdcall;
    TInDllSetBounds                 = procedure (ALeft,  ATop    : Integer;
                                                 AWidth, AHeight : Integer);
                                                stdcall;
    TInDllSetCallback               = procedure (const Context  : PChar;
                                                 const Value    : Pointer;
                                                 const UserData : UIntPtr); stdcall;

    TAppMainForm = class(TForm)
        CreateFormButton: TButton;
        DestroyFormButton: TButton;
        DisplayMemo: TMemo;
        procedure CreateFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure DestroyFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FDllHandle                     : THandle;
        FWindowHandle                  : HWnd;
        FProcCreate                    : TInDllCreateForm;
        FProcDestroy                   : TInDllProc;
        FProcShow                      : TInDllProc;
        FProcHide                      : TInDllProc;
        FProcSetBounds                 : TInDllSetBounds;
        FProcSetCallback               : TInDllSetCallback;
        function Load(
            const FileName     : String;
            const ParentHandle : HWND;
            const LeftPos      : Integer;
            const TopPos       : Integer;
            out   ErrMsg       : String): Integer;
        procedure Unload(const ErrMsg : String = '');
        function  GetProcAddr(const ProcName : String;
                              const ProcAddr : PPointer;
                              out   ErrCode  : Integer;
                              out   ErrMsg   : String): Boolean;
        function InDllOKButtonCallback(Param : UIntPtr) : UIntPtr;
    end;

var
  AppMainForm: TAppMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TAppMainForm.CreateFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    DllFilename : String;
    ErrorMsg    : String;
begin
    DllFilename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TDirectory.GetCurrentDirectory)
                   + 'FormInDll.dll';
    if Load(DllFilename,
            FormToHWND(Self),
            16,
            50,
            ErrorMsg) <> 0 then begin
        DisplayMemo.Lines.Add(ErrorMsg);
        Exit;
    end;
    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('FormInDll loaded');
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TAppMainForm.DestroyFormButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Unload();
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function TAppMainForm.GetProcAddr(
    const ProcName   : String;
    const ProcAddr   : PPointer;
    out   ErrCode    : Integer;
    out   ErrMsg     : String) : Boolean;
begin
    IntPtr(ProcAddr^) := IntPtr(GetProcAddress(FDllHandle, PChar(ProcName)));
    if not Assigned(ProcAddr^) then begin
        Result  := FALSE;
        ErrCode := Integer(GetLastError);
        ErrMsg  := Format('Function "%s" not found. Error #%d',
                         [ProcName, ErrCode]);
        Unload;
    end
    else begin
        Result  := TRUE;
        ErrCode := ERROR_SUCCESS;
        ErrMsg  := '';
    end;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function TAppMainForm.InDllOKButtonCallback(Param: UIntPtr): UIntPtr;
begin
    DisplayMemo.Lines.Add('Data received: "' + PChar(Param) + '"');
    Result := 0;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function InDllOKButtonCallback(
    UserData : UIntPtr;
    Param    : UIntPtr) : UIntPtr;
var
    Form : TAppMainForm;
begin
    Form   := TObject(UserData) as TAppMainForm;
    Result := Form.InDllOKButtonCallback(Param);
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function TAppMainForm.Load(
    const FileName     : String;
    const ParentHandle : HWND;
    const LeftPos      : Integer;
    const TopPos       : Integer;
    out   ErrMsg       : String): Integer;
begin
    Result := ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    if FDllHandle = 0 then begin
        FDllHandle    := LoadLibrary(PChar(FileName));
        if FDllHandle = 0 then begin
            Result := GetLastError;
            ErrMsg := Format('LoadLibrary failed with error #%d', [Result]);
            Unload;
            Exit;
        end;

        if not GetProcAddr('CreateForm', @@FProcCreate, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
        if not GetProcAddr('DestroyForm', @@FProcDestroy, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
        if not GetProcAddr('Show', @@FProcShow, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
        if not GetProcAddr('Hide', @@FProcHide, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
        if not GetProcAddr('SetBounds', @@FProcSetBounds, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
        if not GetProcAddr('SetCallback', @@FProcSetCallback, Result, ErrMsg) then
            Exit;
    end;

    FWindowHandle := FProcCreate(ParentHandle);
    FProcSetCallback('OKButton', @FomInDllAppMain.InDllOKButtonCallback, UIntPtr(Self));
    FProcSetBounds(LeftPos, TopPos, -1, -1);
    FProcShow;
    Result := ERROR_SUCCESS;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TAppMainForm.Unload(const ErrMsg: String);
begin
    if (FDllHandle = 0) or (@FProcDestroy = nil) then
        Exit;
    FProcDestroy;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}

end.
```

Form in the main application as dfm:

```
object AppMainForm: TAppMainForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'AppMain'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 461
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object CreateFormButton: TButton
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'CreateForm'
    OnClick = CreateFormButtonClick
  end
  object DestroyFormButton: TButton
    Position.X = 120.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'DestroyForm'
    OnClick = DestroyFormButtonClick
  end
  object DisplayMemo: TMemo
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [Pan, LongTap, DoubleTap]
    DataDetectorTypes = []
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 224.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 421.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 165.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    Viewport.Width = 417.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 161.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Code for the DLL:

```
{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Author:       Francois.PIETTE@overbyte.be
Creation:     Jan 14, 2020
Description:  Demo DLL for FMX form in a DLL
Disclaimer:   This is free software. Use it at your own risks.
Version:      1.00
History:


 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
library FormInDll;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  WinApi.Windows,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Forms,
  FormInDllForm in 'FormInDllForm.pas' {DllForm};

{$R *.res}

var
    DllForm      : TDllForm;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function CreateForm(ParentForm: HWnd) : HWnd; stdcall;
begin
    try
        if not Assigned(DllForm) then
            DllForm := TDllForm.Create(nil);
        Result := DllForm.AttachToHWnd(ParentForm);
    except
        Result := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    end;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure DestroyForm; stdcall;
begin
    if Assigned(DllForm) then
        FreeAndNil(DllForm);
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure Show; stdcall;
begin
    if Assigned(DllForm) then
        DllForm.Show;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure Hide; stdcall;
begin
    if Assigned(DllForm) then
        DllForm.Hide;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight : Integer); stdcall;
var
    Width, Height : Integer;
begin
    if not Assigned(DllForm) then
        Exit;

    if AWidth >= 0 then
        Width := AWidth
    else
        Width := DllForm.Width;

    if AHeight >= 0 then
        Height := AHeight
    else
        Height := DllForm.Height;

    DllForm.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, Width, Height);
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure SetCallback(
    const Context  : PChar;
    const Value    : TCallbackFunction;
    const UserData : UIntPtr); stdcall;
begin
    if Assigned(DllForm) then
        DllForm.SetCallback(Context, Value, UserData);
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
exports
    CreateForm,
    DestroyForm,
    Show,
    Hide,
    SetBounds,
    SetCallback;

{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure DllMain(Reason: Integer);
begin
  if Reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then begin
    OutputDebugString('DLL PROCESS DETACH');
    FreeAndNil(DllForm);
    FreeAndNil(Application);
  end;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}

begin
    DllProc := @DllMain;
    DllProc(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

And finally code for the form in DLL:

```
{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Author:       Francois.PIETTE@overbyte.be
Creation:     Jan 14, 2020
Description:  Demo FMX form in a DLL
Disclaimer:   This is free software. Use it at your own risks.
Version:      1.00
History:


 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
unit FormInDllForm;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes,
    System.Classes, System.Variants,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
    FMX.Edit, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
    FMX.Platform.Win,
    WinApi.Windows;

type
    TCallbackFunction = function (UserData : UIntPtr;
                                  Param    : UIntPtr) : UIntPtr;

    TDllForm = class(TForm)
        Label1: TLabel;
        DataEdit: TEdit;
        OKButton: TButton;
        procedure OKButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FOKButtonCallback : TCallbackFunction;
        FOKButtonUserData : UIntPtr;
    public
        function  AttachToHWnd(AHandle : HWND) : HWND;
        procedure SetCallback(const Context  : PChar;
                              const Value    : TCallbackFunction;
                              const UserData : UIntPtr);
    end;

var
  DllForm: TDllForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}

{ TDllForm }

{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
function TDllForm.AttachToHWnd(AHandle: HWND): HWND;
var
    FmxFormHWnd: HWnd;
begin
    FmxFormHWnd := FmxHandleToHWND(Handle);
    SetWindowLong(FmxFormHWnd,
                  GWL_STYLE,
                  NativeInt(WS_POPUP or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS or
                            WS_CLIPCHILDREN or WS_SYSMENU));
    SetWindowLong(FmxFormHWnd,
                  GWL_EXSTYLE,
                  WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT or WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
    Winapi.Windows.SetParent(FmxFormHWnd, AHandle);
    Visible := TRUE;
    Result  := FmxFormHWnd;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TDllForm.OKButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if @FOKButtonCallback = nil then
        Exit;
    FOKButtonCallback(FOKButtonUserData, UIntPtr(PChar(DataEdit.Text)));
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
procedure TDllForm.SetCallback(
    const Context  : PChar;
    const Value    : TCallbackFunction;
    const UserData : UIntPtr);
begin
    if SameText(Context, 'OKButton') then begin
        FOKButtonCallback := Value;
        FOKButtonUserData := UserData;
    end;
end;


{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}

end.
```

DLL in form .dfm:

```
object DllForm: TDllForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'DllForm'
  ClientHeight = 78
  ClientWidth = 262
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.Y = -1.000000000000000000
    Text = 'This a form in DLL'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object DataEdit: TEdit
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Enter data here'
    Position.Y = 35.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 145.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object OKButton: TButton
    Position.X = 156.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 35.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'OKButton'
    OnClick = OKButtonClick
  end
end
```

Enjoy,
François Piette

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've read it carefully but I can't implement it, because I'm translating a large VCL software to FireMonkey in order to run it under both Windows and MacOS. I guess the best solution would be merging the DLL with the program (or at least the embedded forms).

Comment: @Logomontanus You never mentioned MacOS until now. That changes things drastically, because DLLs don't work in MacOS. They work far differently over there.

Comment: @Logomontanus I don't understand why you can't implement it. Using almost the same code, you can embed a FMX form into a VCL application or the reverse. I you want to port to MacOS, you must only use with what MacOS support. DLL in MacOS are called DYLIB. But the manipulation I've done with window handles are specific to Windows OS. There is probably an equivalent form in MacOS but I don't know it.

Comment: @Jerry I thought I could build a dll and a dylib (for macos) with the same Delphi library project.

Comment: @fpiette Yes, I could implement this solution for Windows if I find an equivalent solution for MacOS. But since I want to have the same projects for both platforms, I need to know the existence of that MacOS equivalent implementation in advance. Otherwise I'll be forced to discard the library.

Comment: @Logomontanus Yes, but as I mentioned, it works entirely different. In fact, in your question, you mention how you target Windows, but not MacOS. The Mac equivalent has entirely different data types which work in a totally different mechanism.

Comment: @Jerry So, do you think it's worth it to look for the Mac equivalent of embedded forms from a library? Or Is it better not to use libraries?

Comment: @Logomontanus As David mentioned in his comment, you can use packages. But I have to wonder why you wish to do this in the first place.

Comment: @Jerry My goal is to translate a VCL application to FireMonkey in order to run it both in Windows and MacOS. A embedded form from a library is straight forward in VCL. I have to decide which is the optimal path to follow: library, packages, merging...