# Preview handler dll permissions issue

Tags: winapi

I'm creating a preview handler dll for a custom graphics file type associated with an application I've developed. For various reasons the preview handler dll is not able to render the graphic for the preview itself. Instead I'm attempting to do it in the following way.

- My graphics application associated with the file has been modified to accept specific command line parameters (file path, width, height). With these parameters the application loads the file, renders an image and saves it as a .png file in the user's AppData/Roaming folder and then terminates. This works fine if I call the application from the command line with valid parameters. The .png is created as expected.
- When the preview handler is run it calls the application with command line parameters for the file being previewed and dimensions of the preview pane. It does this using the windows function CreateProcess and waits for the application to terminate before continuing.
- The preview handler then loads the .png file and draws it to the preview pane.

The problem I'm experiencing is in the second step. The preview handler calls the application but the application gives an error that it is unable to save the .png file ("Cannot create file. Access is denied"). It seems that the application is being run with less permissions when executed by the preview handler than when I run it myself from the command line.

I have tried changing the save location of the file such as user's AppData/Local the shared ProgramData folder and the application's location, but all give the same result. I've also tried setting various CreationFlags in the call to CreateProcess, but none of them help.

Does anyone know why the application doesn't have permissions to save a file when called from a preview handler and is there anything I can do to get it to work? I realise that this is an unusual way of implementing a preview handler, but it's the easiest way without porting a lot of code. Another advantage is that I'm not replicating the rendering code in the main application and the preview handler, which means that the preview handler can be much smaller.

Note that I'm running on Windows 10.

Comment: If you're handling graphics file types (like .png, .jpeg, etc.) you can provide an IThumbnailProvider instead of a preview handler. It will act as a preview in the Explorer preview pane.

Comment: It's a custom binary file type that I designed, not a standard graphics file.

Comment: Yes, I got that. A .png, a .heic, a .webp, are all custom binary file type if you will. If you have a custom file type of your own that represents an image, you don't need a preview handler to enable the preview pane, you can implement a thumbnail provider. Look at the registry in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.heic for example (if you have the Windows 10 heic extensions). It declares a PerceivedType=image and has a ShellEx\{e357fccd-a995-4576-b01f-234630154e96} node (=> thumbnail provider). It has no preview handler but you still can see a .heic as a preview.

Comment: I see. However, if a thumbnail provider is another low IL dll then I will run into the same problem. Do you know if thumbnail providers have higher permissions than preview handlers by default? Or is the thumbnail provider built into the main application for the file?

Comment: It's the same principle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144118(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the application doesn't have permissions to save a file when called from a preview handler and is there anything I can do to get it to work?

Per the documentation:

[Preview Handlers and Shell Preview Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/preview-handlers)

> Preview handlers are called when an item is selected to show a lightweight, rich, **read-only** preview of the file's contents in the view's reading pane. This is done without launching the file's associated application.
>
> ...
>
> By default, **preview handlers run in a low integrity level (IL) process for security reasons**. You can optionally disable running as a low IL process by setting the following value in the registry. However, it is not recommended to do so. Systems could eventually be configured to reject any process that is not low IL.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    CLSID
       {YOUR HANDLER'S CLSID}
          DisableLowILProcessIsolation
```

> Another advantage is that I'm not replicating the rendering code in the main application and the preview handler, which means that the preview handler can be much smaller.

I would suggest moving the rendering code into a DLL. Export a function that takes a file name/pidl/stream and a target `HDC` as parameters. The function can read from the file and draw to the `HDC` as needed. The main app and the preview handler can then share the DLL, calling the function when needed to render the file directly to their respective UIs. You won't need to create a temp `.PNG` file at all.

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot put my rendering code in a dll for the same reason I can't put it in the preview handler dll. My application and rendering code are created using Delphi FMX, which as far as I know cannot create dlls. I'll try the registry entry.

Comment: @XylemFlow FMX can be used inside of a DLL. The only gotcha is the GDI+ startup, which *normally* should be fine in a housing process, but there are ways fit all to do that, as described in the GDI+ documentation.

Comment: A few days ago you told me that VCL and FMX are not designed to be mixed together. Do you have any links to info on including FMX in a dll?

Comment: @XylemFlow have you read [Writing a FireMonkey DLL for use with a VCL application](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/writing-a-firemonkey-dll-for-use-with-a-vcl-application/amp/) yet? How about [Delphi FMX form from a library (dll) into a panel in the main application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720545/)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those. The registry solution is working for now.